# MPAndroidChart LineChart custom highlight drawable

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I'm using MPAndroid Chart library to draw Line Chart in my Android app. The status of graph is like: 
[image: MPAndroidChart - Line Chart]

I want to change it like this:

[image: Line Chart]

So I want to change MPAnroid Line Chart's points, ts called "Circle Hole" in library. I want to switch this hole to drawable. There is a way I can do that?

The circle hole change code is here:

```
LineDataSet set1 = new LineDataSet(yVals, "DataSet 1");
set1.setDrawCircleHole( true );
set1.setCircleColor( Color.BLACK );
```

Library reference is here: [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart)

Comment: What do you mean by "switch this hole to drawable"? Do you want your own drawable instead of the CircleHole?

Comment: Did you find a solution to change the highlight drawable?

Comment: @Massimo please see my updated answer that includes sample code

Answer (score 15):

Since version 3.0 you can provide your own custom image that will be displayed on selecting a given point on the chart. The instructions below are as per [the wiki](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/IMarker-Interface)

To summarise, you can now use the class called `MarkerImage`:

```
MarkerImage myMarkerImage = new MarkerImage(this, R.drawable.my_drawable);
```

Then:

```
myChart.setMarker(myMarkerImage);
```

To adjust the position of the image, you can call:

```
setOffset(float x, float y);
```

If you don't want to use `MarkerView`, you would probably have to make your own sub-class of [`LineChartRenderer`](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/555176bcdbaf0e92dafe8218789b57e3a20c060c/MPChartLib/src/main/java/com/github/mikephil/charting/renderer/LineChartRenderer.java) and add logic to draw your custom highlight drawable.

Here is a very basic proof of concept:

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;

import com.github.mikephil.charting.animation.ChartAnimator;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.Entry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.LineData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.highlight.Highlight;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.interfaces.datasets.ILineDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.renderer.LineChartRenderer;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.Transformer;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.ViewPortHandler;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by David on 3/01/2017.
 */

public class ImageLineChartRenderer extends LineChartRenderer {

    private final LineChart lineChart;
    private final Bitmap image;

    public ImageLineChartRenderer(LineChart chart, ChartAnimator animator, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler, Bitmap image) {
        super(chart, animator, viewPortHandler);
        this.lineChart = chart;
        this.image = image;
    }

    @Override
    public void drawExtras(Canvas c) {
        super.drawExtras(c);

        Highlight[] highlighted = lineChart.getHighlighted();
        if (highlighted == null) return;

        float phaseY = mAnimator.getPhaseY();

        float[] imageBuffer = new float[2];
        imageBuffer[0] = 0;
        imageBuffer[1] = 0;
        LineData lineData = mChart.getLineData();
        List<ILineDataSet> dataSets = mChart.getLineData().getDataSets();

        Bitmap[] scaledBitmaps = new Bitmap[dataSets.size()];
        float[] scaledBitmapOffsets = new float[dataSets.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < dataSets.size(); i++) {
            float imageSize = dataSets.get(i).getCircleRadius() * 10;
            scaledBitmapOffsets[i] = imageSize / 2f;
            scaledBitmaps[i] = scaleImage((int) imageSize);
        }

        for (Highlight high : highlighted) {
            int dataSetIndex = high.getDataSetIndex();
            ILineDataSet set = lineData.getDataSetByIndex(dataSetIndex);
            Transformer trans = lineChart.getTransformer(set.getAxisDependency());

            if (set == null || !set.isHighlightEnabled())
                continue;

            Entry e = set.getEntryForXValue(high.getX(), high.getY());

            if (!isInBoundsX(e, set))
                continue;

            imageBuffer[0] = e.getX();
            imageBuffer[1] = e.getY() * phaseY;
            trans.pointValuesToPixel(imageBuffer);

            c.drawBitmap(scaledBitmaps[dataSetIndex],
                    imageBuffer[0] - scaledBitmapOffsets[dataSetIndex],
                    imageBuffer[1] - scaledBitmapOffsets[dataSetIndex],
                    mRenderPaint);
        }
    }

    private Bitmap scaleImage(int radius) {
        return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, radius, radius, false);
    }
}
```

Consume it like this:

```
Bitmap starBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.star);
mChart.setRenderer(new ImageLineChartRenderer(mChart, mChart.getAnimator(), mChart.getViewPortHandler(), starBitmap));
```

Explanation: `drawExtras` in `LineChartRenderer` draws the circles. We still want these, so in our `drawExtras` override we call super first. Then we generate a scaled bitmap for each DataSet (DataSets may have different circle radii). We scale the bitmaps to an arbitrary size (10x the circle radius). We then iterate through the Highlights exposed through the LineChart field of our renderer and draw the appropriate bitmap.

Here is a screenshot - you can see the 'star' bitmap instead of the circle on the highlighted index:

[image: a line chart with a star instead of a circle at the highlighted point]

Comment: thanks you @David Rawson , you save me !   myChart.setMarker(myMarkerImage);  it's not working for me , it will override my MarkerView , i try your basic proof of concept , it works ,although it hard for me .  Thank you.

Comment: This question for more about how to write a custom renderer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/43443787/5241933

Comment: It was been a long time , you still share the information , thanks.

Comment: @徐博俊 you are very welcome! I'm glad it helps - was just linking the question about custom renderer